# How can I access the value of 'contacts' outside of the navigator.contactsPhoneNumbers.list()?

Tags: javascript

When I implement this code with DrupalGap, I want to access the value from the function in the navigator.contactsPhoneNumbers.list(), outside if it. I want to create a variable with the HTML table tags to the contact names and phone numbers of the contacts. The access the variable outside of the function.

```
contactCount ='';
navigator.contactsPhoneNumbers.list(function(contacts) {
   contactCount = "<p>Total contacts :" + contacts.length + "</p>";    
}, function(error) {
   console.error(error);
});

alert(contactCount); // This does not shows any value.
```

Comment: You can access it, the variable's in scope, but the value will still be an empty string until the `list()` method has completed and the callback you're passing to it is executed. Javascript is asynchronous, you need to adjust your code/architecture to compensate

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply! could you please explain a little more? How do I adjust my code to get the value outside of list()?

Comment: You can't (unless you resort to waiting for a timeout). Code that needs to run when that var is populated will need to be _inside_ the callback function, unless your code is set up in a different way (think angular js etc). Drupal doesn't have any patterns to help with this, it's plain JavaScript architecture, which is quite a big topic to get your head around if it's unfamiliar

Comment: I'd recommend reading about Page Events in DrupalGap to better understand how to deal with asynchronous operations: http://docs.drupalgap.org/7/Pages/Page_Events